# Get Firestore Subcollections - Permission Denied

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am pulling my hair out at this problem. I am attempting to get documents from a subcollection, like so:

```
func getTransactions(completion: ((_ data: [Any]?) -> Void)? = nil ) {
        if let fbUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            let uid = fbUser.uid
            //Make a call to the Database to load the user
            db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("transactions")
                .getDocuments(completion: { (snapshot, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
        } else {
            print("What")
        }
    }
```

This should theoretically work fine, especially since my rules are like this

```
match /users/{user_id} {
    allow get, create: if request.auth.uid != null
  allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == user_id
}

match /users/{user_id}/transactions/{id=**} {
    allow read, get, create: if request.auth.uid != null
  allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == user_id
}

match /users/{user_id}/secret {
    allow read, write: if false
}
```

But when I run the function, I am getting the good ol' missing permissions error.

> Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.}

Even more confusingly, I can //write// to the location just fine, as well as pull all information on the {user} doc, but I just can't... get access to the transaction (or testing, for that matter) subcollection for some reason.

Any help? Ideas? Input?

[image: Reference of the data structure, in case it's important]

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text, such as security rules.  Copy them into the text of the question and format them as text, so they're easier to read and search.  If I wanted to copy them into my own project for testing, I would end up having to type them all in manually.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Edited to change the rules from an image to text! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with an Android client.  The rules work the way I would expect.